# Add all column values repeated of one data frame to other in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Having two data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':[7],'d':[8]})

   c  d
0  7  8
```

The goal is to add all `df2` column values to `df1`, repeated and create the following result. It is assumed that both data frames do not share any column names.

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  4  7  8
1  2  5  7  8
2  3  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are strings columns names is possible use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with unpack `Series` created by selecing first row of `df2`:

```
df = df1.assign(**df2.iloc[0])
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  4  7  8
1  2  5  7  8
2  3  6  7  8
```

Another idea is repeat values by `df1.index` with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (here first index value of `df2` is same like first index value of `df1.index`):

```
df = df1.join(df2.reindex(df1.index, method='ffill'))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  4  7  8
1  2  5  7  8
2  3  6  7  8
```

If no missing values in original `df` is possible use forward filling missing values in last step, but also are types changed to floats, thanks @Dishin H Goyan:

```
df = df1.join(df2).ffill()
print (df)
   a  b    c    d
0  1  4  7.0  8.0
1  2  5  7.0  8.0
2  3  6  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: What about `df1.join(df2).ffill()` ?

Comment: @DishinHGoyani - ya, another solution, working if not exist nans in original data `df1`, else rather not.